# CSS Not being Applied, and Styles showing as blank?

Tags: css

Ive added some CSS to my page via the CSS file. 
However when I loadup the page the CSS isnt being applied.

When I look into firebug the CSS styles show as empty, i.e

```
.logomain img {
}
.logocorn {
}
```

However when I click on source edit they show ?? i.e

```
.logomain img {
    width: 40% !important;
    padding-left: 40px !important;
}

.logocorn {
    float: right !important;
}
```

Any ideas what is happening ?

Edit : The CSS file is shown below :

```
body {
    color: #7E7171;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1 {
    color: #3B3B3B;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
h2 {
    color: #3B3B3B;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 50px;
}
h3 {
    color: #3B3B3B;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
h4 {
    color: #7E7171;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 14px;
}
h5 {
    color: #3B3B3B;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 13px;
}
p {
    color: #7E7171;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}
code {
    background-color: #F7F4F2;
    color: #7E7171;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
pre {
    background-color: #F7F4F2;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #7E7171;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
blockquote {
    border-left: 5px solid #F7F4F2;
}
blockquote p {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
input {
    padding: 6px;
}
.arrow-down {
    border-left: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-top: 5px solid #404040;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 48px;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
}
.social-header.active .arrow-down {
    top: 50px;
}
a:hover {
    color: #333333;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header ul li {
    display: inline;
}
header {
}
.top-header {
    background-color: #F16252;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}
.home-template .bottom-header {
    background-color: #404040;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.home-template h5 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 62px;
    text-align: center;
}
.home-template .bottom-header a {
    display: none;
}
.archive-template .bottom-header {
    background-color: #404040;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.archive-template h5 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 62px;
    text-align: center;
}
.archive-template .bottom-header a {
    display: none;
}
h1.logo {
    margin-top: 9px;
}
h1.logo a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 50px;
}
h1.post_title a {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.excerpt {
    font-size: 13px;
}
h1.post_title {
    line-height: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.social-header {
    background-color: #404040;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    text-align: right;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}
.social-header .container {
    position: relative;
}
.social-header.active {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.social-header a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.social-header a:hover {
    color: #3DD765;
}
.social {
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: right;
}
.social-header ul li {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.social ul li {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.social a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.social a:hover {
    color: #333333;
}
.social-icons {
}
.social-icons a {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.close-social {
    border-left: 3px solid;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.main {
}
.post h1 a {
    color: #333333;
}
.post h1 a:hover {
    color: #333333;
}
.post-template .author-mobile {
    display: none;
}
.author {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.author ul li {
    text-align: center;
}
.author-image span img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
}
.author-image span .info {
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.author-name {
    color: #F16252;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.post-date {
    color: #7E7171;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.author-mobile {
    color: #7E7171;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.author-mobile img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
.author-mobile span {
    color: #F16252;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 14px;
}
.author-mobile time {
    color: #7E7171;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 14px;
}
.post-template .author-mobile time {
    display: inline;
}
.author-name {
    color: #F16252;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.post-date {
    color: #7E7171;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
span.tags {
    color: #7E7171;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 27px;
}
span.tags i {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.post-container a.more {
    background-color: #F16252;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 19px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.post-container a.more:hover {
    background-color: #3DD765 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
.post-container div.content {
    display: none;
}
p.content {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.post-container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 70px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}
.post-container:hover {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.post-container:hover .post-bottom {
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.post-container:hover article {
    border: medium none;
}
article {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.post-bottom {
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.post-container article {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EEEEEE;
    height: 390px;
    position: relative;
}
h1.post_title a:hover {
    color: #F16252;
}
.postimg-slider {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.loading {
    background-image: url("../images/loading.gif");
}
.postimg-slider ul li {
}
.postimg-slider .prev {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    right: 40px;
    width: 20px;
}
.postimg-slider .next {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    right: 15px;
    width: 20px;
}
.postimg-slider ul {
    list-style-image: none !important;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.postimg-slider ul {
    width: 100%;
}
.postimg-slider ul li {
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.post .postimg-slider ul li img {
    width: 100%;
}
.rslides {
    position: absolute;
}
.rslides_nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.post {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.post a {
    color: #F16252;
}
.post a:hover {
    color: #3DD765;
}
.paginate {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.paginate .older {
    margin-top: 13px;
    text-align: left;
}
.paginate .older a i {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.paginate .page-nr {
    color: #7E7171;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.paginate .newer {
    margin-top: 13px;
    text-align: right;
}
.paginate .newer a i {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.paginate a {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.paginate a:hover {
    color: #F16252;
}
.paginate a i {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 3px;
}
footer {
    background-color: #404040;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 80px;
}
footer p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
footer a {
    color: #3DD765;
}
footer a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.post-template .bottom-header {
    background-color: #404040;
    height: 66px;
    padding-top: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.post-template .bottom-header a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 66px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.post-template .bottom-header a i {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.post-template .back:hover {
    color: #F16252;
}
.post-template h5 {
    display: none;
}
.post ul {
    list-style-image: url("img/red.png");
}
.post li {
    color: #7E7171;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: 17px;
}
.full img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.share {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
.share a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
.share a:hover {
    color: #333333;
}
.share h3 {
    color: #7E7171;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 62px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.share_social {
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.share span {
}
.share span a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F16252;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 39px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
}
.share span a:hover {
    background-color: #3DD765;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
@media (max-width: 410px) {
}
@media (max-width: 455px) {
.social {
    margin-left: -30px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.newer span, .older span {
    display: none;
}
.newer a i, .older a i {
    font-size: 22px;
}
.newer a, .older a {
    font-size: 22px;
}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
.post-template .author-mobile {
    display: block;
}
.post-template span.tags {
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.author {
    display: none;
}
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
}
#add_this {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 242px;
}
.col-md-9 img:nth-of-type(1) {
    width: 0;
}
.logomain img {
    padding-left: 40px !important;
    width: 40% !important;
}
.logocorn {
    float: right !important;
}
```

Comment: Check if any rule is not closed properly (curl braces missing, colon missing, etc)

Comment: I think the css file is cached. Try opening the css file in the browser and refresh a couple of times.

Comment: The source code is showing that the page is returning the css file with the correct class values for CSS (??)

Comment: Can you link to your stylesheet or add it to the question?

Comment: Is the CSS embedded in the head of the HTML file? Or is it in a .css file?

Comment: It's a separate file. I'll upload shortly...and add to question

Comment: The CSS file seems to be in the correct format, see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FT35a/). Do the other CSS styles get applied to your page? If not, it may seem that the whole CSS file is not being correctly loaded - and that solution requires a lot more information on your environment =)

Comment: Please show **both** your HTML and CSS, the problem can be anywhere in either of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering where you have your class set, is it to a `<div>` which would expand the width of the screen or container or something like a `<span>` or an `<a>`. Try it on the `<div>` if not.

Also, If you are using bootstrap for example you could try the classes **.pull-left** and **.pull-right** as they already have good rules associated to them.

Comment: In the end I just used bootstrap .pull-xxx style. Though this is more of a work around, rather then knowing what the actual issue was.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS file seems to be in the correct format, see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FT35a/).

Do the other CSS styles get applied to your page, e.g.

```
body {
    color: #7E7171;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

? If not, it may seem that the whole CSS file is not being correctly loaded - and that solution requires a lot more information on your environment =)

Any error messages in the console?

Comment: Nope and if I copy and paste the CSS back into firebug 'edit live source' if works (??)

Answer (score 0):

Your ending brace for your `@media (min-width:1200px)` aren't closed correctly.

```
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {

    #add_this {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 242px;
    }
    .col-md-9 img:nth-of-type(1) {
        width: 0;
    }
    .logomain img {
        padding-left: 40px !important;
        width: 40% !important;
    }
    .logocorn {
        float: right !important;
    }

}
```

You closed the `@media` before any styles. In your post you have `@media (min-width:1200px) { }`

Comment: This should be fine as the sample provided shows the correct closing brace.

Comment: In your original post, the enclosing braces are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

- first you just check  tag call correctly if u call css as external css,
- then check... did close all brackets of css? and semicolon also for each style,
- then also check media query brackets closed properly?,
- finally run in browser and press Ctrl + F5 for refresh... it will remove cache in old stlyes..